# How to differentiate if this is permutation or combination

Tags: combinatorics

A man has $4$ sons. There are $6$ schools near his house. In how many ways can he send his sons to school, if no $2$ sons are to study in the same school?

As far as I can understand we just need to select in the above problem but the solution says we need to use permutation. In the above problem arrangement does not seem necessary.

Comment: Why don't you provide but you thought and actually say what the solution said

Comment: Permutation is combination with order. Obviously his 4 sons are different and the order does matter.

Answer (score 2):

Just *selecting* the schools that will be filled is obviously not enough.

We could select $4$ schools to fill $\boxed\bullet\boxed.\boxed\bullet\boxed.\boxed\bullet\boxed\bullet$ in $\binom64$ ways, but then individual students could be put into these schools in $4!$ ways, so $\binom64\times 4!$

*Permutations* offer a direct way to the answer, viz $^6P_4 = 6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways